# jQuery selector not working

Tags: jquery

im having some wierd problems with selecting an element with a class.
in my case i have this AJAX query, that returns some links with the same class.
when i click the link an event should happend, but it didn't.
 then i tried with makeing it alert when the an element with the class had been clicked, nothing happends, then i try to make a direct link on the page with the same class, now it gives me the alert.. 
what is happening ? the ajax query checks if the user is online, and does this every 1 minute, the element has the class "friend" and i try to call it by this code:

```
$('.friend').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

nothing happends with the ones displayed by the ajax request. but it responds to the links put directly onto the site.

Comment: this is asked a couple times every day. let me go find a dupe.

Comment: Can you post your HTML for the element with the friend class?

Comment: how is that post similar to this ??

Comment: @Flaashing, oh, this is another question where `delegate`/`live` is the answer rather than `document.ready`. Asked 5 times a day.

Comment: English sentences begin with capital letters. Please take some care over your question if you want me to take any care over an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `live`:

```
$('.friend').live('live',function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

It will append that handler to items that exist and items that **will** exist with that selector.

Comment: well it still doesnt work :/

<a class="friend" title="Name" data-rowid="2" href="#">
<img src="include/user/1320783714_1955.jpg">
</a>

Comment: @Flaashing it works fine (as you can see from the answer you chose [which is the same as mine] but was answered later :-P)

Comment: darn it.. i suck at time, your was ofc the right answer :) 
well it works now, i just had to change som things in th code ;) thanks alot btw are you into php ?

Comment: great :D is this possible ? mysql_query("SELECT * FROM someTable where somerow1 ='$var1' AND somerow2='$var2' OR somevar1='$var2' AND somevar2='$var1' ORDER BY id DESC"); 
??

Comment: @Flaashing ask another SO question. putting that is a comment is a bit unreadable ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Use the live function. It is much more "reliable".

```
$('.friend').live('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I like the idea, but don't like "reliable" quite so much. It's just a different, AJAX orientated, event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the jQuery `click` function only binds to elements which are in the DOM at the moment `click` is run.  So the links added by your `ajax` call come later and hence miss this.  For jQuery < 1.7 use `live` for this type of scenario

```
$('.friend').live('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

For jQuery 1.7 and above use the new unified `on` syntax

```
$(document).on('click', '.friend', function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: `on` wont perform event delegation unless the selector parameter is provided. Try `$(document.body).on('click', '.friend'...)` if you must, but it's essentially the same as `live` at that point, so you might as well just use `live`.

Comment: @zzzzBov yes you're correct. Still adjusting to the new syntax

Comment: me too. I've read the [docs on `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) about 10 times and I still need to reference them every time it's mentioned.